# Настройка цены woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, cms, woocommerce, wordpress-плагины

Работаю с wordpress и woocommerce недавно. Сайт по продаже золотых изделий. Цены на золото меняются часто. Задача стоит в следующем брать текущий курс золота с сайта и по формуле заполнять цены на товары, при чем цены должны постоянно обновляться при смене курса или с заданной периодичностью (например раз в 10 минут). Вопрос такой реально ли это реализовать на woocommerce или не стоит даже браться. Может посоветуете плагин, все которые я находил близки по смыслу задачи но все же не то что нужно. Спасибо!

Comment: Если нет ничего подходящего пишите своё как нужно :)  Можно написать парсер или воспользоватся API известного сайт по курсу валюты. Потом на php написать функцию которая будет делать математические вычисления  по курсу. Так немного теории )

Comment: Заполнять цены у самих товаров будет чуток накладно, если товара много  и постоянно перезаписывать значение в бд. Большая нагрузка как мне кажется.

Comment: Есть например: [Плагин №1](https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/exchange-rates-today/),[Статья обмена валюты](https://booster.io/features/woocommerce-currency-exchange-rates/), [Плагин №2](https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/currency-exchange-for-woocommerce/), [Плагин №3](https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/woo-multi-currency/)

Comment: Есть WooCommerce Currency Switcher https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-currency-switcher/. Позволяет обновлять курс хоть раз в минуту.

Comment: @Даниил из этих плагинов вижу обновление курса чаще, чем раз в сутки, только у Booster (статья обмена валюты), но он монструозный...

Comment: Спасибо большое за ваши ответы, я понял что функционал получения текущего курса на золото и обновление цен на сайте придется написать вручную, а за плагины отдельное спасибо оплата разными валютами тоже пригодится.